# Is there a setting in QGIS that can stop auto-docking of dragged windows?

Tags: qgis, dockable-window

I often find myself dragging windows to get them out of the way of the map, and QGIS decides to dock them in very inconvenient ways. Can be a real pain sometimes, as I have to repeatedly click to undock the window, and wait for QGIS to pop it back out. Is there a setting which can turn this behavior off?

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to press and hold Ctrl when you start the dragging, then it won't try to dock.

Another solution is to edit
\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\QGIS\QGISCUSTOMIZATION3.ini
and set docking to FALSE for certain windows (like Styling)